# MySQL if query returns nothing, try second query

Tags: mysql

I'm crossing everything I have that this is possible...

I currently have some SQL that uses UNION ALL to join a bunch of queries together. It's important that ALL is in there, because these queries could potentially return the same records and I need each instance.

Unfortunately, the individual SELECT's aren't very well thought out. They incorporate a WHERE clause that returns all records where a value matches a user-input value, or is NULL, and I now need these to either return only the records that match, or fall back on to returning the records that are NULL only if nothing is returned by the first attempt...

In other words, I have something like this...

```
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo = bar
OR foo IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo = bar
OR foo IS NULL
```

and I instead need something like this...

```
(
TRY..
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo = bar
..nothing? TRY..
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo IS NULL
)
UNION ALL
(
TRY..
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo = bar
..nothing? TRY..
SELECT foo,bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foo IS NULL
)
```

Is this possible? If so, what would a working example be please?

Comment: Seems that the two query in Union  are the same  so.. you want obtain the result two time?

Comment: I just simplified for the sake of this example. There are actually hundreds of UNION ALL's with different queries in the real script.

Comment: I'm sorry but In the way you proposed  the question  is not clear to me .. try adding a sample of data and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Basically, the part in the pseudo code above that says "..nothing? TRY.." is what I need real SQL for... I need that if the first select returns nothing, run the second query, but if the first returns something then don't. Then the result of this is what's UNION'd to the other results.

Comment: Unfortunately the real SQL is generated on-the-fly by a 200+ line PHP script, and is potentially thousands of lines long. I can guarantee posting the real script is only going to cause further confusion =)

Comment: There is possibly something to do with the [conditionals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of your querygroups, you can use a construct like

```
...
UNION ALL
  SELECT foo,bar
  FROM foobar
  WHERE foo = bar
     or foo is null and not exists (
       SELECT *
       FROM foobar
       WHERE foo = bar
    )
UNION ALL
...
```

This will take either the rows that fulfill your condition, or, if there are no rows that fulfill your condition, are `null`. It can make use of an index on `foo`. It will be a little slower than your current query (because it has to evaluate the query for `foo = bar` twice).